# A field being a sigma field if and only if it's a monotone class

Tags: probability, measure-theory

The exercise is as follows:

"The limit of an increasing (or decreasing) sequence A<sub>n</sub> of sets is defined as its union ∪<sub>n</sub>A<sub>n</sub> (or the intersection ∩<sub>n</sub>A<sub>n</sub>). A monotone class is defined as a class that is closed under monotone limits of an increasing or decreasing sequence of sets. Show that a field B is a $\sigma$-field if and only if it is a monotone class."

This is the very first exercise in S.R.S. Vardhans "Probability Theory" and I am stuck with it, since I don't have a clue how to show this.

What does "closed under monotone limits" mean?
I assume that "increasing sequence of sets" means that A<sub>n+1</sub> > A<sub>n</sub> and A<sub>n+1</sub> < A<sub>n</sub> for a "decreasing sequence of sets". But I don't get the clue what this has to say...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closed under monotone limits: if $(A)_n$ is an increasing sequence ($A_n\subseteq A_{n+1}$) (resp. decreasing sequence $A_{n+1}\subseteq A_n$ ) of elements in $\mathcal{M}$ then  $\bigcup_{n}A_n\in \mathcal{M}$ (resp. $\bigcap_nA_n\in \mathcal{M}$).

Comment: Since a class B, in addition to being a field, is assumed to be closed under countable unions (or equivalently, countable intersections); i.e., if A<sub>n</sub> &isin; B for every n, then A = &cup;<sub>n</sub>A<sub>n</sub> &isin; B and such a class B is called a $\sigma$-field, then we can say that from this additional property follows that B has to be a monotone class. Because the additional property and the very definition of "cloed under monotone limits" are looking very similar. Is there a way to express this is an acceptable manner? And thanks for your answer!

Comment: and please tell me why in the comment the &cup; and likewsie elements aren't rendered

Answer (score 3):

If $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, it is clearly a monotone class. (you may check the definitions).

Conversely, if $\mathcal{A}$ is a monotone class,
for each $\mathcal{A}_n\in \mathcal{A}$, define $B_k:=\cup_{n=1}^k A_n \in \mathcal{A}$, then $B_k$ is increasing, and thus $\cup_{k=1}^\infty B_k=\cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n \in \mathcal{A}$ and hence $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: Why is $\mathcal{A}$ closed under complements, though?