# Question about Monotone Class implies Sigma Field

Tags: probability, monotone-class-theorem

I'm trying to solve this exercise from Resnick "A Probability Path" (1.41) and found the answer on the topic bellow,

[A field being a sigma field if and only if it's a monotone class](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/881859/a-field-being-a-sigma-field-if-and-only-if-its-a-monotone-class)

Therefore, the answer on this topic is about the third postulate of Sigma-field, that says if A1,A2,... belongs to class A implies that the union (or intersection) also belongs.

My question is: How to prove the postulates one and two?

(i) $\Omega$ belongs to class A

(ii) If An belongs to class A implies An complement belongs to class A.

Thanks for help

Comment: This is already given from the definition of a field. The only thing you need to prove additional for the $\sigma$-field is the closure under countable union.

Comment: Got it! I forgot about this detail. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I removed the tag [tag:class-field-theory] because it seemed not to apply. Class field theory is a (big) part of algebraic number theory and has nothing to do with sigma fields. I assume you selected the tag only because it contained relevant sounding words. That recipe often leads one astray here for natural language words have overloaded meanings in various parts of math.

Comment: And... welcome to Math.SE!